# Autoincrement SQL server 2008/c#

Tags: c#-4.0

How do I increment field of table using `varchar`.  Here an example of what I want to have:

```
Mark  00001 
Mark  00002
Mark  00003

Jaques  00001 
Jaques  00002 
Jaques  00003
```

Here is my example It can be useful for other people thanks to those who have helped me a lot thank you

The table is

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TAG_Sinistre](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ref_ag] [varchar](7) NULL,
    [ref_sinistre] [varchar](7) NULL,

)`
```

The stored procedure is

```
 create PROC [dbo].[sp_Add_AgSinistre]
     @ref_ag varchar (7)

AS BEGIN
declare @id  int
 DECLARE @ref_sin VARCHAR
 SET @id = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(ID AS INT)), 0) + 1  
                     FROM TAG_Sinistre where ref_ag=@ref_ag
)

select @ref_sin=right('000000'+CAST(@ref_sin AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
BEGIN

INSERT into TAG_Sinistre(ref_ag,ref_sinistre)
VALUES (@ref_ag,@ref_sin)
```

Comment: do you want to do that in C# code or on the DB side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want the DB side with stored procedure it does'nt work for me

Comment: What would happen if you had *two different* Mark's ?

Comment: It's just an example of what I want to have ! in my case I have name of companies

Comment: Are these two seperate fields, i.e. CompanyName | SequenceNumber ? or are they stored in the same field?

Comment: No they are separated they are not in the same field

Comment: I want to increment the sequenceNumbre while using insert stored procedure Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the *CompanyName* field is `UNIQUE`, you could get the `MAX` added value, and increment that?

```
DECLARE @CurrentSequence INT
SET @CurrentSequence = (SELECT MAX(SequenceId) 
                        FROM TableName WHERE CompanyName = @CompanyName)

INSERT INTO TableName 
(CompanyName, SequenceId) 
VALUES 
(@CompanyName, @CurrentSequence+1)
```

Your StoredProc would pass in the *Company Name* as `@CompanyName`.  Obviously, this is a naive approach, and I'm not including what would happen if multiple attempts to update the company would happen simultaneously, but there's no mention of that ion the question.

**EDIT**: Based on comments

```
DECLARE @maxSeq INT
SET @maxSeq = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(SequenceId AS INT)), 0) + 1 FROM  
                     TableName WHERE CompanyName = @CompanyName)

INSERT INTO TableName 
(CompanyName, SequenceId) 
VALUES 
(@CompanyName, right('000000'+CAST(@maxSeq AS VARCHAR(7)),7))
```

As I said, I would look to use an `INT`, and get the *UI* to present the sequence as you want, instead of casting etc in the DB.

**EDIT 2**: Added Fiddle

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca02d/1)

Comment: The sequenceId is a varchar(7) not an int !

Comment: I thought you meant you needed to check a `varchar` field, i.e. CompanyName.  Why are you looking to use a `varchar` for the sequence number?

Comment: First I am actually in a internship they want to specify each accident happend in a company as 00001, the second 00002 , so it's usefull to do it as varchar !

Comment: Yes it would be helpful I though that it's going to work just as a varchar , and I am using 5 caracters ,I don't know if it's possible to have caracters with int !

Comment: It increment field as 1 2 not as 000001 000002 !!

Comment: I find finally the solution your post helps me a lot Thank you

Comment: I just added a SQL Fiddle, you'll see it adds there as **0000001**.

Comment: The fields were both `varchar`, did you see the fiddle I created?  If it helps, you can upvote or mark as answer.

Comment: I want to share the code but I don't know how it's my first time here !

Comment: I did thank you a lot you gave me the idea thanks ! i updated my question you can see how i get it Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your columns always look like those specified above.

DB Trigger (MS-SQL) --> Pseudocode/Untested:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[YourTable] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @maxVal int
    -- PSEUDOCODE!!!
    SELECT @maxVal = MAX(CAST(dbo.RegexReplace( '.*?(\d+)', myColumn, '$1') AS INT ))
    FROM YourTable

    INSERT INTO YourTable
        SELECT myColumn + ' ' + @maxVal FROM inserted
END
```

Use insert now like this:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable values('Jaques')
```